# Specify number of bins in BinLists

Tags: list-manipulation

`HistogramList` provides a way to specify number of bins. How do I specify the number of bins in `BinLists`?

Comment: For `n` bins (`n > 1`): `BinLists[data, (Max[data] - Min[data])/(n - 1)]`

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[binListsF];
binListsF[data_, binning_: Automatic] := 
 HistogramList[data, binning, BinLists[data, {#1}] &]
```

Examples:

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 20];

binListsF[data]
```

> {{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2},
>     {{-1.29575, -1.76175}, {-0.416754, -0.0148679, -0.191385, -0.34766, -0.185635}, {0.485679, 0.40914, 0.261881, 0.63566, 0.676805,
>       0.1307, 0.0206518, 0.0977624, 0.4083}, {1.5443, 1.09863, 1.31189, 
>      1.51306}}}

```
binListsF[data, 3]
```

> {{-2, 0, 2},
>     {{-0.416754, -1.29575, -0.0148679, -1.76175, -0.191385, -0.34766, -0.185635}, {0.485679, 0.40914, 0.261881, 0.63566, 1.5443, 
>      0.676805, 0.1307, 1.09863, 0.0206518, 1.31189, 0.0977624, 0.4083, 
>      1.51306}}}

```
binListsF[data, 10]
```

> {{-2, -(3/2), -1, -(1/2), 0, 1/2, 1, 3/2, 2},
>     {{-1.76175}, {-1.29575}, {}, {-0.416754, -0.0148679, -0.191385, -0.34766, -0.185635}, {0.485679, 0.40914, 0.261881, 0.1307, 0.0206518,
>       0.0977624, 0.4083}, {0.63566, 0.676805}, {1.09863, 
>      1.31189}, {1.5443, 1.51306}}}

Modify the definition to get the the list of binned elements to

```
 HistogramList[data, binning, BinLists[data, {#1}] &][[2]]
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
ClearAll[binListsF2];
binListsF2[data_, binning_: Automatic] := 
 BinLists[data, {HistogramList[data, binning][[1]]}]

{binListsF2[data] == binListsF[data][[2]], binListsF2[data, 3] == binListsF[data, 3][[2]]}
```

> {True, True}